# How to navigate navigation properties using Linq and a repository pattern?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

Using the [Geneic Unit of Work and Repository Framework](http://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/), I am trying to navigate navigation properties with Linq to Entities.

In my controller, I am using a repository pattern and unit of work.  In this controller, the `_repository` is `Websites`.

Given the following three tables:

[image]

I am trying to get the `Website` entity, as well as a distinct list of `ContentTypes.Description` for all `SourceUrls` for a specific `WebsiteID` and `UserId`.

I can get the initial part of my data:

```
var website = _repository
    .Query()
    .Select()
    .Single(u => u.UserId == userId && u.WebsiteGuid == websiteGuid);
```

I have had several messy attempts, including something like this:

```
                    var website = _repository
                        .Query()
                        .Select()
                        .Single(u => u.UserId == userId && u.WebsiteGuid == websiteGuid)
                        .SourceUrls.Any(s => s.ContentTypeId == s.ContentType.ContentTypeId)
                        .Select(new ContentType());
```

The framework gives me the ability to write out a SQL query through `.SelectQuery(...)`, however I'm trying to avoid this.

I can create a new DTO and cast it to this as well.

Suggestions on how to get this Linq query to work?

Thanks.

**--Update--**

Trying this through the `Website` entity seems to be difficult as there is no direct navigation property `Websites`--`ContentTypes`.

So, Starting from `SourceUrls`, I tried the following:

```
                    var rep2 = _unitOfWork.Repository<SourceUrl>()
                        .Query(q => q.UserId == userId)
                        .Include(i => i.ContentType.Description.Distinct())
                        .Include(i => i.Website)
                        .Select().Where(w => w.Website.WebsiteGuid == websiteGuid).ToList();
```

However I'm getting this new error:

> "The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type.  Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties."

I also tried doing the linking through the `.Select()` but not quite there...

Comment: FYI: `Query()` and `Select()` aren't doing anything for you in the example provided.

Comment: a website can have 1 source url and a single source url can have many content types??

Comment: @jeffdot - With this framework, I can't access `.Single()` without using `.Query().Select()` first... unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @CSharper - I guess that needed some clarification:  `Website` 1..* `SourceUrls` 1..1 `ContentType`.  So each `SourceUrl` only has one `ContentType`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your data model to play with but this *appears to be* working on my local system:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;

public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        var website = _repository
            .Where(w => w.UserId == userIdArg && w.WebsiteGuidArg == websiteGuidArg)
            .
    }
}
```

Your model may give you varying amounts of success with that `Distinct()` but the important things is that you can use include to make sure you get the collections loaded.

I've made this answer community wiki in case any new discoveries require a change to it.

Comment: Going through the framework, I don't see where `.Include()` is exposed.  There is `.Intersect` and everything in there seems to be `IEnumerable` not `IQueryable`.  I try doing `.AsQueryable()` but still no `.Intersect`.  In addition, I don't need to do `_repository.Websites` as `_repository` is `IRepository<Website> _repository;`

Comment: @ElHaix do you have `System.Data.Entity` in your using statements?  That's where the good `Include()` extension is introduced.

Comment: I found the `.Include()` off `.Query().Include()`, however I `ContentTypes` isn't available in `.Include(s => s.SourceUrls // cannot add .ContentTypes)`, and I do see `ContentType` in the list of foreign keys for the `SourceUrl` entity: `public virtual ContentType ContentType { get; set; }`

Comment: Sounds like your model isn't helping.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I think going about it from the `Website` entity is a mess.  So, starting with `SourceUrl` - see my update above.  Hopefully this will be simpler to solve with this?

Comment: @ElHaix You should be able to just not `.Include()` from this direction --by which I mean "Starting at SourceUrl".  I believe you have direct navigation properties and I suspect it will lazy (or eager, but probably lazy) load when necessary.